# Create COM DLL from Unmanaged C++ LIB

Tags: c++, com

I have followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465345/how-do-you-create-a-com-dll-in-visual-studio-2008) to create a COM DLL in Visual Studio 2008. My objective is to wrap an existing unmanaged C++ .lib.

Is there an easy way to implement the COM interface for the lib. Or do I just have to keep adding ATL simple objects which essentially wrap the objects in my library?

For example, I have added the simple ATL object, CMyObject to my COM library, am I to create wrapper code including function members etc in CMyObject that essentially wrap the behavior of MyObject contained in the unmanaged C++ library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to expose your functionality to COM you'll need to perform two major steps:

- introduce COM interfaces
- implement those interfaces using functionality of code you already have

So yes, the scenario you described is the typical way to solve this problem.

Using ATL will simplify things a lot. However you have to take care of exceptions as well. Since your code is in C++ it can throw exceptions. COM doesn't allow propagating exceptions outside COM methods - if the client is not in C++ it will crash once exception is thrown from your code. So your wrapper layer needs to have `try`-`catch` for every method directly called from COM.

Comment: +1, Good point about the exceptions which can be easily missed.

Answer (score 2):

I think adding wrappers the way you describe is the best way to go.  Given that parameter types for OLE will be different to the C++ parameters in many cases, e.g. BSTR rather than string or char*, some wrapping is required for COM.  The only alternative is to have a non-COM DLL.