# Building a COM component using VS2008 express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com

This may be a really stupid question but I can't seem to find how to create a **C++** COM component using visual studio 2008 express.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: I can't see any direct support for that in Visual C++ Express. So you'll have to write code manually. For the usual small COM local server component that means creating a DLL and exporting the well known functions, and placing the right entries in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project's settings, there are two things that I always set in VB.NET and C#:

1. On the Application tab, click Assembly information and check the Make Assembly COM-visible
2. On the Compile/Build tab, check the Register for COM interop

For C++:
[How do you create a COM DLL in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465345/how-do-you-create-a-com-dll-in-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: oopss.. I'm sorry. I'm using C++, not C#. :)

Comment: Thanks, I saw this before but I was hooked on the ATL stuff which the express eddition doesn't have. I'll try the DllGetClassObject thingy :)